# Switch user not working ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ssh, sftp

I created a new user yesterday named portal.
Everything works perfectly when I switch from my first user to portal.

But, today when I want to switch to portal it's not working.
I got an error in FileZilla when I want to SFTP using portal user.

```
Error:  FATAL ERROR: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Then, I tried to ssh using portal user and it also not working.

What could be wrong ? I have been reading alot of post but it's still not working.
Please help.